# HTML/JS questions from a programmer new to web dev

Tags: javascript, html

I i've been searching for an answer to this for about an hour and half, but can't find anything, I think the problem is I don't even really know what to be looking for. I'm fairly familiar with compiled and interpreted languages, but I am just now starting on web dev stuff.  So i'll keep this question simple,

Can someone thoroughly explain what this piece of code does. And possible variations on it. Thank You in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle-variable").show();
    $(".trigger-variable, .variable-dummy").addClass("active");});
```

Comment: It waits until the document is ready, then uses jQuery selectors to do things like showing an element, adding a class etc. Why not spend another hour and a half reading the jQuery documentation, and you'll have this figured out.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is jQuery - a javascript library.

The `$(document).ready(function() {` just says "wait to do this until the document is fully loaded."

`$("#toggle-variable").show();` finds the element with the ID of "toggle-variable" and displays it.

`$(".trigger-variable, .variable-dummy").addClass("active");});` finds all elements with the class of "trigger-variable" or "varible-dummy" and adds the class of "active" to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Wait for the DOM to be loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Make the DOM element with ID 'toggle-variable' be visible
    $("#toggle-variable").show();
    // Add the "active" class to any DOM elements with the class 'trigger-variable'
    // or 'variable-dummy
    $(".trigger-variable, .variable-dummy").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be an element in the DOM with an id of toggle-variable that is hidden,
It is supposed to be shown as soon as the page has finished parsing in the document.ready function.

AddClass is just adding a CSS class active to all the elements having classes either trigger-variable or variable-dummy.

Comment: Thanks! I'm kind of learning by the seat of my pants for a project at work. So this really helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code is written with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Waits until the page is loaded
    $("#toggle-variable").show(); //Shows the element with id toggle-variable
    $(".trigger-variable, .variable-dummy").addClass("active"); //Adds the class active to all elements with the class trigger-variable and/or variable-dummy
}); //closes the function
```